# Auto verify a user in Amazon Cognito User Pools

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I get this error that a user can't change/reset their passwords if I don't set up the email verification in user pools:

```
You have not selected either email or phone number verification, so your users will not be able to recover their passwords without contacting you for support.
```

I want to be able to user forgot password as instructed in the ios user pool tutorial but will need to verify the email using a Pre Sign Up lamba trigger.

How do you use the lambda trigger? I know how to write Lambda functions but not sure on how to verify the email address (so that all emails are verified and I don't care if a user signs up with a garbage one for now). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Pre sign-up trigger to confirm an user's email.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;

    // Return result to Cognito
    context.done(null, event);
};
```

Comment: AuthError: Unrecognizable lambda output
Recovery suggestion: Make sure that the lambda configuration is correct